Receiving 'AccessDeniedException' When Accessing Power BI Reports?
I am using POWERBI Reporting Services on-premises in my company. I have all them the necessary licenses before.
I host it on-premises on my company's own servers.
I created certificates through Power BI Configuration Manager and granted the necessary network permissions for external access. We're experiencing an issue with report display.
When using through a browser:
Active Directory Domain admin users can log in.
Normal users can log in.
When using Power BI Mobile app on Android and IOS:
Active Directory Domain admin users can log in.
Normal users cannot log in.
We're seeking a solution for this problem. You can view the ReportServer error logs as output.
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5280|INFO|45|Received request GET /api/v2.0/SystemReportServerRelativeUrl| RequestID = _a3434b72-a978-4866-91bd-a1e24f1e7b2e
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5280|INFO|50|Received response for notification| RequestID = _bd16c83b-9299-4865-9498-efe95e953215
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5280|INFO|50|Fetched ProductVersion 1.20.8959.122851|RequestID = _a3434b72-a978-4866-91bd-a1e24f1e7b2e
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5280|INFO|45|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 200, Elapsed time 0:00:00.0025927|RequestID = _b9c9e92b-4993-4a23-af1d-231f5417aa177d
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5280|INFO|45|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 200, Elapsed time 0:00:00.0020553|RequestID = _8485b698-072f-475d-8d1c-410fc77c21
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5280|INFO|45|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 200, Elapsed time 0:00:00.0016437|RequestID = _bd16c83b-9299-4865-9498-efe95e953215
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5280|INFO|45|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 200, Elapsed time 0:00:00.0020417|RequestID = _524ca0b4-47d6-41f5-a739-0a89a51068
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5280|INFO|45|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 200, Elapsed time 0:00:00.0027125|RequestID = _a3434b72-a978-4866-91bd-a1e24f1e7b2e
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5280|INFO|45|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 200, Elapsed time 0:00:00.0021378|RequestID = _60281c83-b173-4192-b975-b686dee87fb9e8
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5336|WARN|63|Received a request with an unmatched or no authentication scheme. 401
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5336|INFO|63|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 401
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5436|INFO|45|Received request GET /assets/img/powerbi.png| RequestID = _c57148ed-e200-4bfb-b813-ff7693dfc87f
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5436|INFO|35|Fetched ProductVersion 1.20.8959.122851|RequestID = _9d894296-c06b-4fb8-8a39-12b14a265e8a
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5436|INFO|63|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 200, Elapsed time 0:00:00.0024853|RequestID = _9d894296-c06b-4fb8-8a39-12b14a265e8a
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5436|INFO|63|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 200, Elapsed time 0:00:00.0026031|RequestID = _d5a4d15-8446-70f6f72bf4ed
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5436|INFO|63|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 401, Elapsed time 0:00:00.0025169|RequestID = _d5a4d15-8446-70f672bf4ed
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5592|INFO|46|Received a request with an unmatched or no authentication scheme. 401
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5749|INFO|45|Received request GET /assets/img/splinner_16x16.gif| RequestID = _652580b8-4034-4266-ae4b-3b3f5f506a73
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5749|INFO|45|Received request GET /api/v2.0/SafeSystemResourceContent(type='UniversalBrand', key='logo')| RequestID = _7d7a1c6-6cf7-7d4d-3eae-5d44e5a4d3b
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5749|INFO|45|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 200, Elapsed time 0:00:00.0027553|RequestID = _7d7a1c6-6cf7-7d4d-3eae-5d44e5a4d3b
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5749|WARN|63|Received request with an unmatched or no authentication scheme. 401
2024-10-01 15:49:45.5749|INFO|63|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 401
2024-10-01 15:49:45.6200|INFO|45|Received request GET /api/v2.0/catalogitems| RequestID = _5a4fc68d-3af2-45f7-ba19-4b41d3b1a107
2024-10-01 15:49:45.6200|INFO|45|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 200, Elapsed time 0:00:00.0088811|RequestID = _5a4fc68d-3af2-45f7-ba19-4b41d3b1a107
2024-10-01 15:49:45.6200|INFO|45|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 200, Elapsed time 0:00:00.002763|RequestID = _d5a4d15-710f-5f3f-7d44e5a4d3b
2024-10-01 15:49:45.6200|WARN|63|Received a request with an unmatched or no authentication scheme. 401
2024-10-01 15:49:45.6200|INFO|63|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 401
2024-10-01 15:51:10.3369|ERROR|63|libraryThrowing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException: The permissions granted to user 'DOLMRK\powerbi' are insufficient for performing this operation.| RequestID = _5a4f68d-3af2-45f7-ba19-4d3b1a107
2024-10-01 15:51:10.3369|ERROR|63|libraryThrowing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.AccessDeniedException: The permissions granted to user 'DOLMRK\powerbi' are insufficient for performing this operation.| RequestID = _s6817db-428a-4a88-86ba-366b0ba18ba
2024-10-01 15:51:10.5363|INFO|50|Sending response. Response code DOLMRK\powerbi 403, Elapsed time 0:00:00.004836|RequestID = _5a4f68d-3af2-45f7-ba19-4d3b1a107

